# Is there a Kotlin/Java DI framework supporting this kind of injection of generics?

Tags: java, kotlin, generics, dependency-injection, composition

Let's say, like a good developer trying to follow composition over inheritance, I have a function that is generic over a class X providing two interfaces:

```kotlin
fun <X> X.doTheThing() where X: SomeCapability, X: SomeOtherCapability {
    ...
}
```

Is there a Dependency Injection framework that I can use in Kotlin that will let me call such a function without having to supply the arguments manually, given some definitions of how to provide the interfaces `SomeCapability` and `SomeOtherCapability`?

Since most DI frameworks are class-based, I'd also be happy if something like this is possible, but with classes instead. For instance, maybe:

```kotlin
class DoTheThing<X>(val ctx: X) where 
  X: SomeCapability, 
  X: SomeOtherCapability {
    fun justDoIt() {
        with(ctx) {
              doTheThing()
        }
    }
}

// At use sites
class SomeClass {
    // Type projection here, because the DI 
    // framework will supply an
    // appropriate class satisfying
    // the bounds of DoTheThing
    @Inject
    later it var injected: DoTheThing<*>
}
```

Ideally, I'd like this to be a compile-time DI framework, but that's not a strict requirement for me.

Comment: Isn't the requirement of `SomeCapability` and `SomeOtherCapability` from the implementation of `doTheThing()`? Why it need some injection?

Comment: @James Lan, I've edited the class-based version to supply some clarification for this.

Comment: The idea is that the DI framework should be able to inject the X argument, so that the function can be called without having the user explicitly supply an X.